# How to train LSTM with current timestep feature also?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am having a training data set for a time-series dataset like below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
train_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 16)))
train_df.columns=['var1(t-3)','var2(t-3)','var3(t-3)','var4(t-3)','var1(t-2)','var2(t-2)','var3(t-2)','var4(t-2)','var1(t-1)','var2(t-1)','var3(t-1)','var4(t-1)','var1(t)','var2(t)','var3(t)','var4(t)']
train_X=train_df.drop(['var1(t)'],axis=1)
train_y=train_df[['var1(t)']]
```

So as you see for training I am inputting the network with past three timesteps of the all 4 variables and the current timestep of the three remaining variables which makes up to 15 variables.

I want to train this is in an LSTM with functional API in Keras because I cannot use sequential API in my case. So I tried the below:

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
visible = Input(shape=(100,15))
hidden1 = LSTM(10)(visible)
hidden2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden1)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden2)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')


history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=64, epochs=2, validation_split=0.2)
```

Then I reshape the train and test like below:

```
train_X=train_X.reshape(train_X.shape[0],1,train_X.shape[1])
train_y = train_y.reshape(train_y.shape[0],1)


train_X shape is (100, 1, 15)
train_y shape is (100,1)
```

But this gave a very huge MAPE and RMSE.So I think my reshaping is wrong here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add `train_X` and `train_y` shape in your question?

Comment: I have added it and also it can be reproducible from my question.

Answer (score 1):

**Original Answer:**

LSTM takes inputs in 3D and you are passing a 2D Input which explains the `ValueError`. You should preprocess your data so that it fulfills the requirement `[batch, timesteps, feature]`. Your data should be presented in a way that each row represents a timestep.

Let's create dummy data with 4 variables

```
train_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)))
train_df.columns =['val1','val2','val3','val4']
train_df.head()
```

Output:

```
    val1  val2  val3  val4
t0    93    78    78    53
t1    38    30    48    39
t2    92    88    18     5
t3    56     8    36    59
t4    13     1    20    22
```

Each row represents values at time t. You want to lookback 3 timesteps to predict `val1` at t=4.

Now I would pre process the data that it fulfills the requirement of 3D tensor.
I've created a function that would do the preprocessing as follows:

```
def create_time_series(data, time_steps, look_forward, target_col, n_features):

    x = []
    y = []
    
    for i in range(time_steps, len(data)):
        x.append(data[i-time_steps:i,:])
        y.append(data[i:i+look_forward, target_col])
    
    x, y = np.array(x), np.array(y)

    x = np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], x.shape[1], n_features))
    y = np.reshape(y, (y.shape[0], y.shape[1]))

    return x, y

data = train_df.values 
time_steps = 3  #We want to use previous 3 values to predict the next value
look_forward = 1 #We want to predict 1 time step ahead.
target_col = 0 #Target column is the 1st column i.e (Val1).
n_features = 4 #We are using 4 features

x_train, y_train = create_time_series(data,time_steps,look_forward,target_col,n_features)
```

Now we've created 3D tensor and is ready to be passed through LSTM layer.

```
visible = Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1],x_train.shape[2]))
hidden1 = LSTM(10)(visible)
hidden2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden1)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden2)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=2, validation_split=0.2)
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Suppose you have 3 columns with features and a 4th column containing target value then you could generate dummy data using

```
train_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)))
train_df.columns =['val1','val2','val3','target']
```

Since you want to pass the 3 features `val1`, `val2` & `val3` with their values at time `t` to predict the `target` value at time `t`, you can create 3 more features which would represent shift in  `val1`, `val2` & `val3` using.

```
train_df['val1shift'] = train_df['val1'].shift(-1)
train_df['val2shift'] = train_df['val2'].shift(-1)
train_df['val3shift'] = train_df['val3'].shift(-1)
train_df = train_df[['val1',  'val2',  'val3', 'val1shift',  'val2shift',  'val3shift', 'target']]
```

Output:

```
    val1   val2  val3   val1shift   val2shift   val3shift  target
t0    63    17    86       13.0       57.0       63.0      14
t1    13    57    63       85.0       20.0       60.0      62
t2    85    20    60       72.0        4.0       58.0      74
t3    72     4    58       70.0       22.0       25.0       6
t4    70    22    25       23.0       15.0       49.0      52
```

Now each row would contain values for `val1`, `val2` & `val3` at time `t` and `t+1` or you could say time `t-1` & time `t`.

After creating this dataframe you could create time series that will be passed to LSTM using

```
data = train_df.values 
time_steps = 3  #We want to use previous 3 values to predict the next value
look_forward = 1 #We want to predict 1 time step ahead.
target_col = 6 #Target column is the last column.
n_features = 7 #We are using 7 features

x_train, y_train = create_time_series(data,time_steps,look_forward,target_col,n_features)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question yet. The problem is that I cannot use the information of `val2,val3,val4`  at `t=t` to predict the `val1` at t=t.You are still using the values from `t=(t-3)` and `t=(t-1)` and not making use of `val2,val3,val4`  at `t=t`

Comment: In the original post you asked about dimension error, I gave solution to that. If your original question was about using information about `val2,val3,val4` then you should have asked 2 questions. 1st you should have asked about how to resolve `Value Error` which you've removed by editing the orignal question. 2nd question should be asked on how to use information of `val2,val3,val4` at `t=t`.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. So my question was actually to reshape with 15 variables  (3-time lags of 4 variables and current timestep 3 variables `val2,val3,val4`) so that's why I combined both.